# Named Blueprints with factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, machinist

I am using Factory Girl but like the machinist syntax. So I wonder, if there is any way creating a named blueprint for class, so that I can have something like that:

```
User.blueprint(:no_discount_user) do
  admin           false
  hashed_password "226bc1eca359a09f5f1b96e26efeb4bb1aeae383"
  is_trader       false
  name            "foolish"
  salt            "21746899800.223524289203464"
end

User.blueprint(:discount_user) do
  admin           false
  hashed_password "226bc1eca359a09f5f1b96e26efeb4bb1aeae383"
  is_trader       true
  name            "deadbeef"
  salt            "21746899800.223524289203464"
  discount_rate { DiscountRate.make(:rate => 20.00) }
end

DiscountRate.blueprint do
  rate {10}
  not_before ...
  not_after ...
end
```

Is there a way making factory_girl with machinist syntax acting like that? I did not find one. Help appreciated.

Thx in advance
Jason

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. require blueprint syntaxe

```
  require 'factory_girl/syntax/blueprint'
  Sham.email {|n| "#{n}@example.com" }

  User.blueprint do
    name  { 'Billy Bob' }
    email { Sham.email }
  end

  User.make(:name => 'Johnny')
```

Comment: shingara, 

I know, thats the way I'm using it. But the question ist, if one can use named blueprints like: 

User.blueprint(:no_discount_user) do
and
User.blueprint(:discount_user) do

so that I can call:

User(:discount_user).make to create a user with a discountrate
and
User(:no_discount_user).make to create a user without. 

It would make Cucumber step definition much dryer in my case. But it seems I need to switch to machinist instead.

Comment: Yes I think it's not possible. The extension of factory_girl can't made that

Answer (score 0):

If you concerned with DRYness of your tests, you may consider [active_factory plugin](https://github.com/tarasevich/active_factory/), that i've created. In it you could define a factory like this:

```
factory :discount_user, :class => User do
  admin           false
  hashed_password "226bc1eca359a09f5f1b96e26efeb4bb1aeae383"
  is_trader       true
  name            "deadbeef"
  salt            "21746899800.223524289203464"
  discount_rate { DiscountRate.make(:rate => 20.00) }
end
```

Another option would be just 'add discount' inside your test:

```
models { discount_rate - user - ... }
```

It would create association between the two models. Thus you can keep your specs DRY while avoiding creating a lot of factories.

Sorry, if I'm not answering exactly your question